# OSGi container-managed JPA (4.2.6)doesn’t commit transaction

Tags: hibernate, jpa, osgi, jta

I'm using OSGi, Karaf 2.3.1 , Hibernate 4.2.6.Final , container-managed JPA and container-managed JTA.
My code doesn't work without flush(). **But after flush() rollback doesn't work.**

Question is: **Does workaround exist?**

the problem for 4.2.2 was described here [Transactions with Hibernate in Apache Karaf / OSGi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16800462/transactions-with-hibernate-in-apache-karaf-osgi)
  Switching to 4.2.6 did not help.

in resent samples I could see flush() as well
https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/documentation/src/main/docbook/quickstart/tutorials/osgi/managed-jpa/src/main/java/org/hibernate/osgitest/DataPointServiceImpl.java

```
public void deleteAll() {
   entityManager.createQuery( "delete from DataPoint" ).executeUpdate();
   entityManager.flush();
}
```

Thank you.

My detailed configuration:

```
Apache Karaf (2.3.1)
==== Hibernate Bundles 
[ 179] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   80] jackson-datatype-hibernate4 (0)
[ 197] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   80] wrap_mvn_org.hibernate.javax.persistence_hibernate-jpa-2.0-api_1.0.1.Final (0)
[ 477] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   80] hibernate-commons-annotations (4.0.4.Final)
[ 478] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   80] hibernate-core (4.2.6.Final)
[ 479] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   80] hibernate-entitymanager (4.2.6.Final)
[ 480] [Active     ] [Created     ] [       ] [   80] hibernate-envers (4.2.6.Final)
[ 481] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   80] hibernate-osgi (4.2.6.Final)

==== Aries Bundles 
[   8] [Active     ] [Created     ] [       ] [   20] Apache Aries Blueprint Core (1.1.0)
[   9] [Active     ] [Created     ] [       ] [   20] Apache Aries Blueprint CM (1.0.1)
[  11] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   20] Apache Aries Proxy Service (1.0.1)
[  12] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   20] Apache Aries Util (1.1.0)
[  13] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   20] Apache Aries Proxy API (1.0.0)
[  14] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   20] Apache Aries Blueprint API (1.0.0)
[  24] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   30] Apache Aries JMX API (1.1.0)
[  28] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   30] Apache Aries JMX Core (1.1.1)
[  36] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   30] Apache Aries JMX Blueprint Core (1.1.0)
[  39] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   30] Apache Aries JMX Blueprint API (1.1.0)
[ 160] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   30] Aries JPA Container API (1.0.0)
[ 161] [Active     ] [Created     ] [       ] [   30] Aries JPA Container blueprint integration for Aries blueprint (1.0.1)
[ 162] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   30] Aries JPA Container (1.0.0)
[ 163] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   30] Aries JPA Container Managed Contexts (1.0.1)
[ 164] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   30] Apache Aries JNDI API (1.0.0)
[ 165] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   30] Apache Aries JNDI Core (1.0.0)
[ 166] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   30] Apache Aries JNDI RMI Handler (1.0.0)
[ 167] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   30] Apache Aries JNDI URL Handler (1.0.0)
[ 168] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   30] Apache Aries JNDI Support for Legacy Runtimes (1.0.0)
[ 338] [Active     ] [Created     ] [       ] [   30] Apache Aries Transaction Blueprint (1.0.0)
[ 339] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   30] Apache Aries Transaction Manager (1.0.1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade to Hibernate 4.2.7 as there is some OSGi fixes for transactions with hibernate.

Comment: Thanks a lot, have switched to hibernate 4.2.7 and issue has been resolved.